# Metric distortion caused by smooth mapping on a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ is a smooth map from a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ to itself.  Let $x,y$ be points on $M$ and assume that $y,\phi(y)$ are not in the cut-locus of $x$.  Then is it possible to compute $\kappa_{\phi}$ such that
$$
\|Log(x,y)\|\leq\kappa_{\phi}\|Log(\phi(x),y)\|?
$$

If not can we give a (reasonable) upper bound on $\kappa_{\phi}$?

Comment: If $M$ is compact, and you are calculating these logarithms at $x$, they are not really needed, since the distance is the same in the manifold and in the geodesic normal coordinates.

Comment: If $M$ is not compact, then these logarithms might not be defined, even if the cut locus of $x$ is empty.

Comment: Good, point but technically my space (though I didn't mention it is Hadamard..so I know the logs are globally defined (also in this case there is no cut-locus)).  

Also how would you measure the distortion in Euclidean space (since we can use normal coordinates in the compact case)?

Comment: I don't see how to answer in all generality. $\kappa_\phi$ can be arbitrary, so you need to tell more about what you are after. What kind of property of $\phi$ would you assume?